# IE errors when destroying DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, datatables

I encountered a compatibility issue on my project between Internet Explorer 10 and `DataTable.destroy()`. I have many DataTable and when I change or add a data, I use Ajax and `$("#" + this.id).DataTable.destroy()` to rebuild the table.

Below is the code used to initialize the DataTables :

```
        $('.tableReleves').each(function( index ) {
        if(this.childElementCount>1) {
            $("#" + this.id).DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "info": false,
                "searching": false,
                "retrieve": true,
                "language": {
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "«",
                        "next": "»",
                    }
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"type": "currency", "targets": this.id.contains('apres') ? [-2, -1] : -1}
                ]
            });
        }
    });
    toDestroy = true;
```

After update or add a new data, I used this to update my dataTable

```
if(toDestroy) {
    $('.tableReleves').each(function( index ) {
        if(this.childElementCount>1) {    
            $("#" + this.id).DataTable.destroy()
        }
})
```

}

(the toDestroy variable is used to avoid to call this part during the page loading)

This work fine on chrome or Firefox, but show an error on IE.

> Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or
>   undefined

I tried some methods like draw(), clear() but nothing worked onto the three web browsers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a very old post , but as I faced the same problem , here I am marking the solution what I did. My code was also working fine in other browsers except IE. IE has an issue of destroying datatable function if the `class` `datatable` is not associated with the `table` tag.

Check the table has the `class` `datatable` before destroying. Change your code as mentioned here.

```
if(toDestroy) {
    $('.tableReleves').each(function( index ) {
        if(this.childElementCount > 1) {   
          if ($("#" + this.id).hasClass('dataTable')) {
            $("#" + this.id).DataTable.destroy();
         }
      }
})
```